# Customizing the branch icons on a QtTreePropertyBrowser?

Tags: qt, branch, stylesheet

I inherited a code project and am tasked with redesigning the GUI with Qt's Style Sheets.

There is a subclassed `QtTreePropertyBrowser` which I've styled to change the background colors/font color, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the appearance of the branch indicator icons. They're almost invisible on the new dark background, like such:

[image]

Doing some googling, I found [this example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview).

But from my experimenting so far, it hasn't worked. Reading the documentation, it seems that `QtTreePropertyBrowser` inherits from `QTreeView`, but I don't know why it's not working. Any insights?